# Failed to initialise tesseract engine but I do have all my files

Tags: c#, tesseract

I have a problem with Tesseract.
I'm trying to get the text in an image, so I followed a tutorial.

Here's my code:

```
        var testImagePath = @"C:\Users\Zonedetec\Documents\test\test2\ana.png";
        var dataPath = (new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.Parent.FullName) +@"\tessdata\";

        try
        {
            using (var tEngine = new TesseractEngine(dataPath, "fra", EngineMode.Default)) //creating the tesseract OCR engine with English as the language
            {
                using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(testImagePath)) // Load of the image file from the Pix object which is a wrapper for Leptonica PIX structure
                {

                    using (var page = tEngine.Process(img)) //process the specified image
                    {
                        var text = page.GetText(); //Gets the image's content as plain text.
                        MessageBox.Show(text);

                        // Console.WriteLine(page.GetMeanConfidence()); //Get's the mean confidence that as a percentage of the recognized text.  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error!" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
```

The link to the tessdata folder is the right one, I checked in debug mode.
The error is at :

```
 using (var tEngine = new TesseractEngine(dataPath, "fra", EngineMode.Default)) //creating the tesseract OCR engine with English as the language
```

And it says:

> failed to initialise tesseract engine! see https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/wiki/Error-1 for more details

But I don't understand because in my tessdata folder, I have all the files that can be found here in "Always copy":
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/tree/master/fra

Can someone help me get the tesseract working?

Thanks :)

Comment: I do not know much about Tesseract, but it is 5 years old. One of the things I would check is that you are using the same version of dotnet framework.

Comment: Do you have a powerful and free OCR to advise me?

Comment: I did a search for "ocr nuget" and found this page, https://nugetmusthaves.com/Tag/OCR